# Python loading (kind of) screen

Tags: python

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ymQ.png)
im trying to make a kind of loading screen that does like . and than .. and than ... like a wait thingy
but it doesnt work ofc bc i suck with python, can someone help me out?

Can someone just tell me whats wrong with it? Bc the error tab doesnt show anything wrong with it. I have tried to rerun the program remake the code and even put those ands that u see in the picture. but nothing works. I also tried removing the other code bc i thoud the other code was causing problems but turns out it doesnt.

Comment: Don't post images. They're not helpful. Add your code (properly formatted) to your question. See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not post the code as a screenshot. You can write it in the text of the post and put three apostrophes (like ```) at the beginning and at the end of code block.

To make a "loading screen" you can use several print functions.

By default, each print() call ends with a newline character (`\n`). You can change this behavior using the `end` argument. So, the `print('.', end='')` call will not end with a new line, and you can continue printing on the same line.

So, to print 3 dots, you need to write:

```
for _ in range(3):
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    sleep(0.5)
print()
```

The number 3 in the `range` function argument determines the number of points, you can change it at your discretion.

Calling `print()` at the end is necessary so that next time the text is printed on a new line.

The `and` operator you tried to use is a logical operator and can be used in an `if` statement. For example, the condition `if a > 0 and b > 0` will be satisfied only if both variables `a` and `b` are greater than zero.

Also in the comparison `if question1 == ("7/2")` you can remove the parentheses and compare `question1` with a string `"7/2"`.

Comment: Nice catch on the use of `flush=True`. :)